# Не могу понять, почему мой цикл прерывает всю программу...(программа с сортировкой элементов в массиве)

Tags: c

Значит, у меня есть программа, которая сортирует элементы в массиве. Пользователь вводит capacity и элементы в массиве, но элементы должны быть [0...100]
Я, честно говоря, не могу понять, почему из-за цикла моя программа не работает. Насколько я понимаю, местоположение верное. Будьте добры, помогите.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
 
        int i, j, a, n, number[100];
        printf("Enter the capacity of array.  \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
 
        printf("Enter the numbers. Should be strictly [1...100]: \n");
        
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            scanf("%d", &number[i]);
            
          
        
        while (number[j] > 100 || number[j] < 0) {
              break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        {
 
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                

                } 
 
                if (number[i] > number[j]) 
                {
                   
                    a =  number[i];
                    number[i] = number[j];
                    number[j] = a;
                    
                
                }
 
            }
 
        }
 
        printf("The numbers arranged in ascending order are given below: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            printf("%d\n", number[i]);
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
Enter the capacity of array.  
3
Enter the numbers. Should be strictly [1...100]: 
66 77 89 
exited, segmentation fault
```

или:

```
Enter the capacity of array.  
3
Enter the numbers. Should be strictly [1...100]: 
0
12
88
exited, segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А что вы делаете здесь:

```
while (number[j] > 100 || number[j] < 0) {
    break;
}
```

да еще и с **неинициализированным индексом** `j` - переменная `j` может иметь *любое* значение, в том числе и выходящее далеко за пределы массива.

Код - даже с правильным значением `j` - совершенно бессмысленный: он просто либо зацикливает программу при неверном значении некоторого (какого именно?) элемента массива...

Если

> если пользователь вводит меньше 0 или больше 100 - то программа должна останавливаться

то можно так:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &number[i]);
        if (number[i] > 100 || number[i] < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Wrong number %d\n",number[i]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Или даже

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &number[i]);
        assert(number[i] <= 100 && number[i] >= 0);
    }
```

Comment: так как мне поставить лимит? в плане если пользователь вводит меньше 0 или больше 100 - то программа должна останавливаться. я просто понять не могу....мне казалось мое решение достаточно логичным

Comment: Например, так, как я дописал в ответ - если надо программу завершать.